# Check object type in arraylist - ERROR:Game.update() failure

Tags: java, eclipse, object, slick2d

I have an array of sprites:

```
ArrayList<Sprite> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Where each sprite is added to the array list using:

```
list.add(createSprite(name, x, y))
```

I am trying to check if the type of sprite my player (currently at x and y) is moving into is "ball" using this:

```
Loader.getSpriteType("ball", x + delta_x, y + delta_y)
```

in my `public void move(int dir)` method.

but while the app loads, it immediately crashes declaring

```
 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
```

There is no Game class in my project, so I am unsure how to fix this error. The getSpriteType method works well in other instances and the app works fine without it so I'm certain the error is here.

Are there any instances of this happening due to a method like this being called in a non-static method? `getSpriteType` is static.

EDIT: Here is the stacktrace

```
Fri Oct 13 21:28:40 AEDT 2017 ERROR:448
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 448
at app.Loader.getSpriteType(Loader.java:26)
at app.Sprite.moveToDest(Sprite.java:105)
at app.Player.update(Player.java:46)
at app.World.update(World.java:20)
at app.App.update(App.java:61)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
at app.App.main(App.java:98)

Fri Oct 13 21:28:40 AEDT 2017 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:669)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
at app.App.main(App.java:98)
```

Comment: Lot of questions and speculations but only 2 lines of code.

Comment: I wasn't sure what would be relevant/helpful as I'm unsure what this error itself is. Please let me know what else I can add to make this a more helpful question as the program itself  is very large

Comment: can you share the stacktrace of your exception ?

Comment: Stacktrace included - apologies